# Liberty Buildpack stalls/freezes sporadically when deploying War

Tags: java, war, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, buildpack

When executing a push of a war file to Bluemix using the server directory method, sometimes the buildpack freezes/stalls on the following step :

```
2016-02-15T18:21:41.08+0000 [STG/5]      OUT -----> Downloaded app package (68M)
2016-02-15T18:21:41.27+0000 [STG/5]      OUT -----> Downloaded app buildpack cache (1.2M)
2016-02-15T18:21:50.13+0000 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Liberty Buildpack Version: v2.2-20151119-1720
2016-02-15T18:21:50.14+0000 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Retrieving IBM 1.8.0_20150828 JRE (ibm-java-jre-8.0-1.11-pxa6480sr1fp11-20150828_01-cloud.tgz) ... (0.0s)
2016-02-15T18:21:51.06+0000 [STG/0]      OUT          Expanding JRE to .java ... (0.9s)
2016-02-15T18:21:52.06+0000 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Retrieving App Management 1.12.0_20151001-1521 (app-mgmt_v1.12-20151001-1521.zip) ... (0.0s)
2016-02-15T18:21:52.19+0000 [STG/0]      OUT          Expanding App Management to .app-management (0.1s)
2016-02-15T18:21:52.22+0000 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Downloading Auto Reconfiguration 1.10.0_RELEASE from https://download.run.pivotal.io/auto-reconfiguration/auto-reconfiguration-1.10.0_RELEASE.jar (0.0s)
2016-02-15T18:21:53.48+0000 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Retrieving com.ibm.ws.liberty-2015.10.0.0-pi52103-201511191720.tar.gz ... (0.0s)
2016-02-15T18:21:54.36+0000 [STG/0]      OUT          Installing archive ... (0.8s)
2016-02-15T18:21:54.38+0000 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Retrieving com.ibm.ws.liberty.ext-2015.10.0.0-pi52103-201511191720.tar.gz ... (0.0s)
2016-02-15T18:21:55.15+0000 [STG/0]      OUT          Installing archive ... (0.7s)
2016-02-15T18:21:55.15+0000 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Retrieving wxsclient-wlp_8.6.0.8-Pcf81547.17192424.esa ... (0.0s).
```

This issue can usually be solved by re-pushing the application, and is unpredictable. How can I troubleshoot / resolve this ?

Comment: Does it seem to be stuck on the same request every time? How long do you wait before killing and pushing again?

Answer (score 0):

Try the same on the v2.7 Liberty Buildpack, it was pushed to production toward the end of March:

https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/liberty/updates.html